# Implementing the Android NavDrawer across all activities

Tags: android, layout, navigation

I have created an Activity in Android Studio and selected the Navigation Drawer layout. Android has then created an automated navigation layout that has a drawer than can be pulled out and provides me with navigation options.

I have edited all of the options to suit my navigation and also edited the images. I have fully coded the Intents that will take the user to the correct activity when the corresponding option is clicked.

I am very new to this and I was wondering, what is the best possible way for me to implement this same navigation layout on all of my activities? I have read about Base Activities but I do not want to specify my own layout as i feel this  Android one is exactly what im looking.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways that I know of going about creating a navigation drawer that is accessible from every screen in your app.

1. It is important to note that you don't necessarily need to create a separate activity for every screen that a user might see in your application. If you wish to only change the "content" of the screen, but keep the same basic toolbar, navigation drawer, and surrounding "frame" layout, it is normally better (and more efficient) to use a [fragment](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) instead. This way, you can do almost all of the same things you can do with separate Activities, but you only need to create the Navigation Drawer once when the app is opened. Google now recommends building applications this way (as you can see in [this post](https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2018/05/use-android-jetpack-to-accelerate-your.html)) as they are better / more flexible at sharing data between screens than Activities are, among other reasons...
2. If you really want to stick to creating multiple activities with the same drawer, then you should create a separate method and layout file specifically for the drawer, then implement them in all the activities you create. Here's a generic example (the views/ids/attributes used don't actually exist, they're just there for demonstration - replace them with whatever you're using in your application):

   a. Write a separate layout file containing the contents of the navigation drawer...

   [res/layout/layout_drawer.xml]

   ```
   <DrawerViewSomethingIdk
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="250dp">

       <DrawerItemThing
           android:id="@+id/drawerItemId"
           android:layout_height="24dp"
           android:layout_width="match_parent"
           android:text="This is a drawer item." />

   </DrawerViewSomethingIdk>
   ```

   b. Use an `<include>` tag to add the layout to every activity layout that you create; a more specific explanation of how to use this tag can be found [here](https://developer.android.com/training/improving-layouts/reusing-layouts).

   ```
   <RootLayoutView
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_width="match_parent">

       <include layout="@layout/layout_drawer"/>

       <!-- everything else in your activity -->

   </RootLayoutView>
   ```

   c. Write a **static** method to bind the views in the drawer to each `Intent` you want them to start.

   [NavigationDrawerUtils.java]

   ```
   public static method bindIntents(Activity activity) {
       DrawerItemThing aDrawerItemView = activity.findViewById(R.id.drawerItemId);
       aDrawerItemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
           @Override
           public void onClick(View v) {
               // start the activity
           }
       });

       // ... and so on for every drawer item you create
   }
   ```

   d. Call the method in each activity, just after the layout file is inflated.

   ```
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity1_layout);
       NavigationDrawerUtils.bindIntents(this);
   }
   ```

Option 2 will function, but its use cases are limited. I highly suggest looking into fragments (Option 1) instead, as filling your application with unnecessary activities will only result in having to reuse the same code multiple times throughout your project and will make it incredibly difficult to maintain.